# pdfbox keep whitespaces on beginning from line

Tags: formatting, pdfbox, spaces

i have a PDF and i want to get the Text of this PDF with PDFBox 2.x an i want to keep all Whitespaces on the beginning from the Line!

Here the PDF Examples:

First Example with seven Whitespace on the Line-Beginning

[image: First Example with seven Whitespace on the Line-Beginning]

when i mark the Text in the PDF and copy it to a Editor i get this:

```
>        Erster Testuebertrag auf die Neuentwicklung fuer die PSA Direktbank ma
>        l mit sehr langen Verwendungszweck gleich zum testen wann dieser cuted
```

EDIT: here is the Stream-Dump from this Sectionimage:

```
BT
/F19 8.9664 Tf 96.197 606.119 Td [(Kommunikation)]TJ
ET
q
1 0 0 1 85.238 594.35 cm
[]0 d 0 J 0.398 w 0 0 m 0 7.352 l S
Q
BT
/F19 8.9664 Tf 133.856 595.758 Td [(Erster)-600(Testuebertrag)-600(auf)-600(die)-600(Neuentwicklung)-600(fuer)-600(die)-600(PSA)-600(Direktbank)-600(ma)]TJ
ET
q
1 0 0 1 85.238 583.989 cm
[]0 d 0 J 0.398 w 0 0 m 0 7.352 l S
Q
BT
/F19 8.9664 Tf 133.856 585.397 Td [(l)-600(mit)-600(sehr)-600(langen)-600(Verwendungszweck)-600(gleich)-600(zum)-600(testen)-600(wann)-600(dieser)-600(cuted)]TJ
ET
```

Second Example with five Whitespaces in second Line

[image: Second Example with five Whitespaces in second Line]

when i mark the Text in the PDF and copy it to a Editor i get this:

```
> Rueckzahlung mal mit Umlauten obwohl das ganze ja gar nicht mehr gehen
>      duerte, aber hier haben wir jetzt sogar die zweite Zeile erreicht
```

EDIT: this is the Stream-Dump of the Sectionimage #2:

```
BT
/F19 8.9664 Tf 96.197 267.821 Td [(Kommunikation)-8400(:)]TJ
ET
q
1 0 0 1 85.238 256.052 cm
[]0 d 0 J 0.398 w 0 0 m 0 7.352 l S
Q
BT
/F19 8.9664 Tf 117.716 257.46 Td [(Rueckzahlung)-600(mal)-600(mit)-600(Umlauten)-600(obwohl)-600(das)-600(ganze)-600(ja)-600(gar)-600(nicht)-600(mehr)-600(gehen)]TJ
ET
q
1 0 0 1 85.238 245.691 cm
[]0 d 0 J 0.398 w 0 0 m 0 7.352 l S
Q
BT
/F19 8.9664 Tf 123.096 247.099 Td [(duerte,)-600(aber)-600(hier)-600(haben)-600(wir)-600(jetzt)-600(sogar)-600(die)-600(zweite)-600(Zeile)-600(erreicht)]TJ
ET
```

So, when i extract the Text with

```
PDFText2HTML Stripper = new PDFText2HTML();
```

or

```
PDFTextStripper Stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
```

the i get every Time the Text without leading Whitespaces on the Line-Beginning but i need it ;)

Example:

```
> Erster Testuebertrag auf die Neuentwicklung fuer die PSA Direktbank ma
> l mit sehr langen Verwendungszweck gleich zum testen wann dieser cuted
> 
> Rueckzahlung mal mit Umlauten obwohl das ganze ja gar nicht mehr gehen
> duerte, aber hier haben wir jetzt sogar die zweite Zeile erreicht
```

Is there every Solution to keep the Whitespaces with PDFBox 2.x?

Greats

Comment: Can you share the pdf in question? Just because some text is indented like there were 5 or 7 spaces doesn't mean there actually are 5 or 7 spaces there.

Comment: i need only a tipp for a example for PDFBox that also parse the whitespaces, because the Description of PDFTextStripper is "This class will take a pdf document and strip out all of the text and ignore the formatting and such"
What is the alternative ... ??

Comment: you can see the pdf as the images, there are whitespaces and im sure. that was the reason that i bring the example with the copy/paste to the editor and i can mark it (only in the second Image the first Line have no Whitespaces on the beginning, u can see, is not markable (yellow))
its a bank-document, i can't share it (only share it to you for private use)

Comment: send it to tilman at snafu dot de. However if this is a document with personal data, do not send it to me unless you have the permission of the person(s) mentioned in the document.

Comment: For my address see my profile here. And as @Tilman  (he belongs to the core PDFBOX contributers, by the way) mentioned, please make sure you are allowed to send the file.

Comment: *you can see the pdf as the images, there are whitespaces* - no, I can merely see that there is a gap. Whether it is created using space characters or using some text positioning instruction, I cannot see. The way it is highlighted in comparison with your working sample, seems to favour the latter alternative. And in that case there is no space character to extract.

Comment: ok, i think i understand it ;)
my question is edited now and i added the stream-dump of this sections.
Now i think there are no whitespaces ^^ and i have to read the postion-attributes of the lines after the line "Kommunikation" and have to analyse if the position X from first line smaller then the postion X from second line (after "Kommunikation")

any example for this? ;) ^^

Comment: There are multiple questions on stackoverflow about text extraction with coordinates using pdfbox.